# How to boot from USB. error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>

Tags: usb, grubrescue

I tried with LS and SET ROOT=... and SET PREFIX=...  for all possibilities, but when I come to INSMODE NORMAL its response is:

```
error: unknown filesystem. 
grub rescue>
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Best to see details. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info You may have file system corruption or other issues. Did you have an abnormal shutdown?

Comment: Yes, it shutdown couple times without reason!! This cant help me, because I cant go out of grub rescue and put system up.

Comment: Shutdown is a different issue and often hard to debug. Is system overheating? But if it was in the middle of something file system may be corrupted and you need to use Live installer in live mode and run e2fsck to repair file system. sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda1  OR whatever partition(s) are Linux formatted with ext type formats.

Comment: No, is not overheating. Is doing that, sometimes when pc is moved.

Comment: That could be a loose connection somewhere? Did you run fsck? POst link to BootInfo report.

Comment: Is look like that.No, i didnt. I will try, but unfortunately i have now dificulty to install system again. I am trying to boot from USB but pc is not detecting USB. Is detecting external keybord but not usb. Is same usb from first time instalation of Ubuntu, bootable and Booting priority settings are changed in Bios.Any help?

Comment: Is this a new UEFI system? Windows is known to change UEFI settings. If BIOS, you may need new flash drive, if old one was somehow overwritten. But otherwise I do not know why it would not boot if it did before.